# Selecting autocomplete lists with Selenium - have to close one list before accessing another

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write a Python script with Selenium to autocomplete a form.

There are several fields with auto-complete. I can fill these out and select as follows:

```
field1 = driver.find_element_by_id("field-1")
field1.send_keys("input")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[1]/li[1]") #this clicks on the first autocomplete option
```

This works fine.

However, in order to proceed to the next form, I have to first simulate a click away, and usually delay by 5-8 seconds:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()
time.sleep(delay)
```

Delay is usually set at 8 seconds - any less and it seems to not work from time to time.

Is there a more efficient way to do this that avoids using a timed delay?

I thought that possibly I need to exit the form / let Selenium confirm that the autocomplete has been selected.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it has helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for an element to be located in the new form. This way you wouldn't have to explicitly declare a delay functionality and the code will resume execution once the new form becomes present.

Sample code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
delay = 3 # seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
    print "new form is ready!"
    # add your code here
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

You can also use any other type of method to find the locator.